# Using a variable in the filename textfield of CSV dataset config in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, csv-file

I want to parameterize the filename textfield of CSV dataset config. I am writing into different files for every user that I'm using in JMeter, hence I need to parameterize the filename option in the CSV dataset config to read the files I create for every user. How can i do that?

I'm using a user-defined variable called csvFilename which I'm referring to as `${csvFilename}` in the filename option of CSV dataset config element. I'm writing into this variable the path of the filename from a BSF post-processor:

```
vars.put("csvFilename","/home/abhijeet/load_test_plans/users//"+username+".csv");
```

(BFS post-process enables reading variables from JMeter). In the above line of code, a username is another variable that will change according to the username I fetch from a CSV file.

So my problem is that the variable `${csvFilename}` is not replacing the file's path into the Filename textfield of CSV dataset config. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also tried this:
I used a BeanShell script function in the path to place the username in the filename textfield of CSV dataset config like this:

/home/abhijeet/load_test_plans/users/${__BeanShell(vars.get("username"))}.csv

But this is not working too. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I could not find any solution to this problem I'm facing I implemented a workaround for it by writing code into a BeanShell PreProcessor that would work like a CSV dataset config element.

The code i've written is:

```
import java.io.*;

String uname = vars.get("username");
System.out.println("Username at the preprocessor: "+uname);
String file_path="/home/abhijeet/load_test_plans/users//"+uname+".csv";
FileReader f = new FileReader(file_path);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(f);

String line = null;
String pt_id, first_name, last_name;
int file_counter = 0;
int gbcount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("global_counter"));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    if(file_counter == gbcount){
        String[] fields = line.split(",");  
        pt_id = fields[0];  
        first_name = fields[1];
        last_name = fields[2];

        vars.put("patientID",pt_id);
        vars.put("fname",first_name);
        vars.put("lname",last_name);
        break;
    } else {
        file_counter++;
    }

gbcount++;
vars.put("global_counter",String.valueOf(gbcount));
```

Comment: please click the check box next to your answer so that your question can be removed from the unanswered list.